# Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, docker, nginx

In this code must be an error due to empty arguments in the `mysqli_connect` function. But browser display different error. As I know `mysqli_connect` function installed by default. Where is the problem or my mistake? How I can fix it?

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:fpm

# Update system core
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

# Start PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

index.php

```
<?php mysqli_connect('', '', '', '', '', ''); ?>
```

Error in browser:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 3
```

Comment: Sounds like mysqli has not been installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Dockerfile you need add mysqli extension:

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm

# Update system core

RUN apt update && apt install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev


RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Start PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Please reduce your answer to the relevant parts - there is no need to install a ton of other extensions if only a MySQL connector is needed

Comment: I have this error: ERROR: Service 'php-fpm' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt update && apt install -y         libfreetype6-dev         libjpeg62-turbo-dev         libpng-dev libxml2-dev libcurl4-gnutls-dev' returned a non-zero code: 127

Answer (score 6):

In your Dockerfile for PHP-FPM (I recommend the Alpine version) you have to install MySQLi extension separately

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

# Update system core
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli

# Start PHP-FPM
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: I have an error: ERROR: Dockerfile parse error line 5: unknown instruction: DOCKER-PHP-EXT-INSTALL

Comment: @LexXy I made a typo, see the updated answer - added the `RUN` I also added the enable command after I tested.

Comment: I did. Try removing that line and re-running. It may not be necessary.